# Windows Ctrl + Double Click to open a folder in new window

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

On some Windows OS'es, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Double Click</kbd> on a folder opens the folder in a new window.  I like this behavior!  But this only seems to be the default for certain versions of Windows (Windows 7 and various Server products).  How can I change this setting for XP? (or in general)?

Comment: New window should be the default unless something has affected your system

Comment: Strange, if I highlight 2 folders and hold ctrl and double click, it opens one in a new window and the other in the same window, but it will never open just one in a new window on a single select, strange indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the option universally (ie. opening a folder will always open a new Window) with Tools | Options | Open each folder ...

You can also "open in new window" on the context menu of a folder or drive in the list (not the tree view).